# "Fīliolō me auctum scito, salva Terentia"; what is "me" role in this phrase?

Tags: classical-latin, latin-to-english-translation, ablative

Is "Fīliolō me" the ablative of the phrase or "me" refers to "me auctum" in the accusative? If is in the ablative, how does it translates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be clearer if we add the implicit *esse*:

> Fīliolō mē auctum *esse* scitō

(It's common to leave out forms of *esse* for brevity; they're seldom actually necessary.)

Now it's clear this is an indirect accusative+infinitive construction: the main verb is *scitō*, the accusative is *mē*, and the infinitive is *auctum esse*.

> *(literally)* Know me to have been increased
>
> *(that is)* Know that I have been increased

Since *auctum esse* is passive, it can take an ablative noun indicating who's doing the increasing: *fīliolō*, by a baby son.

Here are some possible translations into English:

> Know that I've been enriched by a baby son
>
> Know that my life has been made better by my new baby son

Comment: If you add *esse,* aren't you answering a different question?

Comment: @Hugh The *esse* is implicit: it's like how _ego tē amō_ and _tē amō_ are semantically the same (they just have different emphasis).

Comment: The examples in L&S suggest that *scio* +Acc and Infinitive means 'to know how to.' But 'To be aware of,' 'to appraise,' is plain Accusative (or +Genitive). Have I misread it?

Comment: @Hugh I interpreted L&S to say _sciō_ + acc = "I am aware of this thing", _sciō_ + inf = "I know how to do this", _sciō_ + (ut, acc+inf, quod, etc) = "I know that this thing happened"

Answer (score 3):

*Me* is accusative subject of the infinitive (*auctum* = *auctum esse*) in indirect statement triggered by the imperative form *scito*. *Filiolo* is ablative of means: 'Know that I have been enriched/enhanced by (provided with) a little son.'

For the record, this is from the opening of Cicero, *Ad Atticum* I.2.

Answer (score 0):

Every student of Latin soon learns about the **Ablative Absolute..**
This is used when the Noun and the Participle have no position in the clause as Subject or Object. So in this Sentence [the opening words](http://perseus.uchicago.edu/perseus-cgi/citequery3.pl?dbname=PerseusLatinTexts&query=Cic.%20Att.%201.2&getid=0) are in the Ablative because they are "loosed from" (Absolute) from the clause, (confer: *Nominativus Pendens)*

> L. Iulio Caesare, C. Marcio Figulo consulibus

However, if the Noun Participle phrase is the Subject it ought to be Nominative:
And, if it is the **object** of the verb (here= *scito),* then it will be *accusative* (here= *me)* and the participle will also be accusative in agreement (here= *auctum).*

> ***Scito*** know ***me*** me ***auctum*** having been increased ***fīliolō*** by one little son.

--apologies for the mangled English.